# Loop thru multiple URLs in Python - InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with an web-scrapping code that I'm developing.

The code with one URL works perfectly. But when I try to include the loop to scrape multiple URLs the code returns with an error. Each time I modify it, it returns a different error. Now it's erro "InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format(url))".

Here is the code:

```
from typing import DefaultDict
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

from requests.sessions import default_headers

nome=[]
posicao=[]
nacionalidade=[]
idade=[]
clube=[]
contrato=[]
valor=[]

tf = f"http://www.transfermarkt.com.br"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}

pagina = range(1)


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        for lea in pagina:
            print(f"Extraindo links da página {lea}")
            r = req.get(url.format(lea), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            link = [f"{tf}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "td", class_="hauptlink")]
            links.append(link)
        print(f"Collected {len(links)} Links")
    time.sleep(1)
    for url in links:

        r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        r.status_code

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  

        player_info= soup.find_all('tr', class_=['odd', 'even'])

        for info in player_info:
         player = info.find_all("td")
         vall= info.find('td', {'class': 'zentriert hauptlink'})
        
        nome.append(player[2].text)
        posicao.append(player[3].text)
        nacionalidade.append(player[4].img['alt'])
        idade.append(player[5].text)
        clube.append(player[6].img['alt'])
        contrato.append(player[7].text)
        valor.append(vall)
    time.sleep(1)   
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(
            {"NOME":nome,
             "POSICAO":posicao,
            "NACIONALIDADE":nacionalidade,
            "IDADE":idade,
            "CLUBE":clube,
            "CONTRATO":contrato,
            "VALOR":valor}
        )
    print(df)
    df
#df.to_csv('MBB.csv', index=False)
main("https://www.transfermarkt.com.br/berater/beraterfirmenuebersicht/berater?ajax=yw1&page={}")
```

Can anyone help me with this issue?

Bests regards.

Comment: Please add the full traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have two nested lists

```
link = [f"{tf}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
            "td", class_="hauptlink")]

links.append(link)
```

Here you make a list of links and then append it to the `links` list. So, something like this

```
[['url1', 'url2', ...], ['url24', 'url25', ...], ...]
```

So here

```
r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
```

In the first iteration of your for loop, url is the first element of links, which is a list instead of a string.

```
r = requests.get(['url1', 'url2', ...], headers=headers)
```

So requests doesn't know what to to with the list.

There are many possible solutions for this, the one with the least amount of changes would be using extend instead of append.

Replace this

```
links.append(link)
```

With this

```
links.extend(link)
```

This way you are extending `links` with the elements in `link` instead of just appending lists.

Comment: Hi Matias!

Thank you so much for the answer. Did work!

But now I have two other issues on my code.

Can you take a look?