# Loop duplicating results

Tags: python

I'm writing a code for web-scrape Transfermarkt website, but I'm having some issues on the code.

The code had returned an error that was fixed thru the topic: [Loop thru multiple URLs in Python - InvalidSchema("No connection adapters were found for {!r}".format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70661303/loop-thru-multiple-urls-in-python-invalidschemano-connection-adapters-were-f/70665195#70665195)

After this fix, other problems came in.

First: the code is duplicating the results on data frame.

Second one, the code is taking only the last element of each URL. In fact, what I want is get all the agencies URLs in the `pagina = range(1)` and then scrape all players in each agency, thru the URL scrapped in the first part.

ps.: `pagina = range(1)` it will be `range (1,40)`, its the numbers of pages that i will scrape to get all agency's links.

Can anyone give me a hand on this issues?

Thanks!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import time

from requests.sessions import default_headers

nome=[]
posicao=[]
nacionalidade=[]
idade=[]
clube=[]
contrato=[]
valor=[]

tf = f"http://www.transfermarkt.com.br"

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0'
}

pagina = range(1,5)


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        links = []
        for lea in pagina:
            print(f"Extraindo links da página {lea}")
            r = req.get(url.format(lea), headers=headers)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            link = [f"{tf}{item.next_element.get('href')}" for item in soup.findAll(
                "td", class_="hauptlink")]
            links.extend(link)
        print(f"Collected {len(links)} Links")
    time.sleep(1)
    for url in links:

        r= requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        r.status_code

        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')  

        player_info= soup.find_all('tr', class_=['odd', 'even'])

        for info in player_info:
         player = info.find_all("td")
         vall= info.find('td', {'class': 'zentriert hauptlink'})
        
        nome.append(player[2].text)
        posicao.append(player[3].text)
        nacionalidade.append(player[4].img['alt'])
        idade.append(player[5].text)
        clube.append(player[6].img['alt'])
        contrato.append(player[7].text)
        valor.append(vall)
    time.sleep(1)   

    df = pd.DataFrame(
            {"NOME":nome,
             "POSICAO":posicao,
            "NACIONALIDADE":nacionalidade,
            "IDADE":idade,
            "CLUBE":clube,
            "CONTRATO":contrato,
            "VALOR":valor}
        )
    print(df)
    df
#df.to_csv('MBB.csv', index=False)
main("https://www.transfermarkt.com.br/berater/beraterfirmenuebersicht/berater?ajax=yw1&page={}")
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code in this question as well

Comment: Code included as well.